# TypeScript Error in Ionic App: Cannot use async in firebase login

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

In my ionic App I am trying to create a signup code that will check duplicate entry in database and if no duplicate entry found it will allow user to create account using Email and Password. When user want to signup he/she has to provide user data and a unique GroupID, if this GroupID is already available in database user cannot signup with that GroupID.

```
async signup(): Promise<void> {
    this.checkValidEmail(this.user.email, (isError) => {
        if (isError) {
            console.log("Error : Already has this email address ");
            this.error = "Already has this email address in out system";
        } else {
            this.checkValidGroup(this.user.GroupName, (isError1) => {
                if (isError1) {
                    console.log("Error : Thid Group Id is already Taken ");
                    this.error = "This Group ID is not available";
                }
                // this.userService.pushUser(this.user);
                else if (this.matchPassword(this.user)) {
                    console.log("Error :Don't metch password");
                    this.error = "Don't metch between Password and confirm password";
                } else if (this.user.password.length < 6) {
                    console.log("Error : passwrod short");
                    this.error = "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters).";
                } else {
                    this.deleteconfirm(this.user);
                    var pass = Md5.hashStr(this.user.password);
                    this.user.password = pass.toString();
                    var pin = Md5.hashStr(this.user.passcode);
                    this.user.passcode = pin.toString();

                    const loading: Loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
                    loading.present();

                    const email = this.user.email;
                    const password = this.user.password;
                    try {
                        const signup: firebase.User = await this.authProvider.signup(
                            email,
                            password
                        );
                        await loading.dismiss();

                        if (this.userService.pushUser(this.user)) {
                            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
                            this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
                        }

                    } catch (error) {
                        await loading.dismiss();
                        const alert: Alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            message: error.message,
                            buttons: [{
                                text: 'Ok',
                                role: 'cancel'
                            }]
                        });
                        alert.present();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

But this code is showing some error like

```
Cannot find name 'await'.
```

and `Property 'signup' does not exist on type 'AuthProvider'.` any Help Please?

Comment: `await (isError) =>`....  do it for all anonymous function

Comment: You mean like `this.checkValidEmail(this.user.email, await (isError) =>`

Comment: Yep... I meant that!!!